# Command line arguments as a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

For ex:

```
python3 test.py Tejas ALL
or
python3 test.py Tejas EAM EAB EAC
```

The arguments should be store as a  list variable like:

```
cli_arg = ['Tejas', 'ALL']
or 
cli_arg = ['Tejas', 'EAM', 'EAB', 'EAC']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys

argsList = [arg for index, arg in enumerate(sys.argv) if index != 0]

print(argsList)   // Output - ['Tejas', 'EAM', 'EAB', 'EAC']
```

As @Tomerikoo pointed out - Much simpler code below

```
argList = sys.argv[1:]
```

Comment: Thanks @Teths0 for your help. This is working for me.

Comment: @Avinash Make sure you upvote and accept the answer if it works

Comment: Why not just `argList = sys.argv[1:]`? Much simpler